# video upload in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, upload, rubygems

Is there any gem or plugin for uploading videos in rails application? can anybody suggest a gem or plugin for uploading videos in rails 3? please help me in this regard with a tutorial.. Im new to rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a gem for this very specific reason: https://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip-ffmpeg